# GDataXML write file with xmlns namespace

Tags: namespaces, xml-namespaces, gdataxml

I'm using GDataXML and I encounter some problems to write a XML file.
I followed Raywenderlich's tutorial but i have to add some namespaces.

for example after this:
   
 [FooElement addChild:bar1Element];
   
 [FooElement addChild:bar2Element];
   
 [FooElement addChild:bar3Element];
   
 [FooElement addChild:bar4Element];

i would like to do something like that:
   
 [FooElement addNamespace:@"xmlns="https://foo/bar/"

to get this result in file:

    < Foo **xmlns="https://foo/bar/"**>

        < bar1 > xxxx < /bar1 >

        < bar2 > xxxx < /bar2 >

        < bar3 > xxxx < /bar3 >

        < bar4 > xxxx < /bar4 >

     < /Foo >

thanks for help !

Answer (score 7):

i found a solution:

```
GDataXMLElement *FooElement = [GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"Foo"];
NSArray *namespaces = [[NSArray alloc] 
      initWithObjects:[GDataXMLNode namespaceWithName:nil    
      stringValue:@"https://foo/bar/"], nil];
[FooElement setNamespaces:namespaces];
```

I hope this will help =)